# Average length of partitions

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I'm wondering if there's a known asymptotic for an average number of terms for partitions of a given number?
(I mean, given all the partitions of a given number, how many terms do they have on average?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was apparently answered in 1941 by Erdos and Lehner [see here](https://www.projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077492649); however, I only have access to a 1995 [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2154239?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) by Fristedt, which cites the result as (2.2):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P_n \left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6n}} Y_1 - \log \frac{\sqrt{6n}}{\pi}\le v\right)=e^{-e^{-v}}$$

Here, $P_n$ denotes probability measure, with all partitions of $n$ equiprobable.  $Y_1$ denotes the size of the largest part of a partition.  By considering [conjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Conjugate_and_self-conjugate_partitions), the average size of the largest part of a partition equals the average number of parts of a partition.

---

More details, by request.  This formula gives more than just the average of $Y_1$, it gives a lot of information about the probability distribution of $Y_1$.  For example, taking $v=0$, we get $Y_1 \le  \frac{\sqrt{6n}}{\pi} \log  \frac{\sqrt{6n}}{\pi}$ with limiting probability $e^{-1}\approx 0.37$. Taking instead $v=2$, we get $Y_1\le  2\frac{\sqrt{6n}}{\pi}+ \frac{\sqrt{6n}}{\pi}\log  \frac{\sqrt{6n}}{\pi}$ with probability $e^{-e^{-2}}\approx 0.87$.  Hence, subtracting, we get $$Y_1\in \left[\frac{\sqrt{6n}}{\pi}\log  \frac{\sqrt{6n}}{\pi},2\frac{\sqrt{6n}}{\pi}+ \frac{\sqrt{6n}}{\pi}\log  \frac{\sqrt{6n}}{\pi}\right]$$ with probability $e^{-e^{-2}}-e^{-e^{-0}}\approx 0.51$.

If you just want the answer to the original question, it is $$Y_1=O\left(\frac{\sqrt{6n}}{\pi}\log  \frac{\sqrt{6n}}{\pi}\right)=O(\sqrt{n}\log n)$$

Comment: Could you please explain how this translates into asymptotics for $n\propto\ldots$? Should I solve the inequality for $Y_1$, replacing $v$ with $n/2$?..

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a graph of the average number of partitions as a function of the source number:

[image]